# Cisco 1142 AP not joining WLC

Tags: cisco, wifi

I have one an issue that I would be extremely grateful for help with. When I check the AP join statistics I see the following:

Reason For Last Unsuccessful Attempt    RADIUS authorization is pending for the AP

I don't run a radius server and don't know how to get around this so that the device can join.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

What model and version is your WLC? We ran into something similar a couple years ago when we put our first 1142 LAP in. I don't remember if we encountered this specific error, but what we did learn was that the WLC 2100 series requires software version 5.2 or later to talk to the 1140 series LAPs.

If that isn't it, Cisco has a pretty lengthy [troubleshooting document](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6366/products_tech_note09186a00808f8599.shtml) that might be of help.

Comment: I have more information that might be helpful:

 

I have a 4402 controller. I have further seen that the 1142 is somehow in mesh(bridge mode) and as such wont attach to the controller be cause the controller wants its mac address for authentication against a radius server. I added its mac in AP policy under security, but it now wants AAA authentication.

Comment: This is pretty much what Cisco suggests in the document I linked to ("problem 17"). Maybe the AP just needs to be rebooted after being added to the WLC's authorization list?